# Doctrine: Exception in One-To-Many cascading: Integrity constraint violation 1451

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony4, cascade

I am trying to build a very basic CMS using `Symfony` and `Doctrine`. I have entities emulating my sites' structure like so:

**Entity: Page**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ContentTree\PageRepository")
 */
class Page extends SortableBase
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"sort_order" = "ASC"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Website", inversedBy="pages", cascade={"all"}, fetch="EAGER")
     */
    private $website;

    /**
     * Owning side of relation
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Section", mappedBy="page", fetch="EAGER")
     */
    private $sections;


    public function __construct()
    {
    ...
```

**Entity: Section**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ContentTree\SectionRepository")
 */
class Section extends SortableBase
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Page", inversedBy="sections", cascade={"all"}, fetch="EAGER")
     */
    private $page;

    /**
     * Owning side of relation
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Entry", mappedBy="section", fetch="EAGER")
     */
    private $entries;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\SectionTemplating\SectionType", fetch="EAGER")
     */
    private $sectionType;


    public function __construct()
    {
```

**Entity: Entry**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ContentTree\EntryRepository")
 */
class Entry extends SortableBase
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Section", inversedBy="entries", cascade={"all"}, fetch="EAGER")
     */
    private $section;

    /**
     * Owning side of relation
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\ContentTypes\Content", mappedBy="entry", fetch="EAGER")
     */
    private $contents;


    public function __construct()
    {
    ...
```

So in the end a `Page` can have `Sections` which can have `Entries` and so forth. Now, from what I gathered from the [docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations) I was under the assumption that with how I setup the `cascades` I could just go and use the `EntityManager` to remove an instance of any Entity (lets say `Section`) and it would automatically delete that instance as well as all contained `Entries`.

However, when I do something like:

```
$section = $this->getSectionByID($sectionid);

$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$entityManager->remove($section);
$entityManager->flush();
```

as soon as the `Section` has any `Entries`, I get:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM section WHERE id = ?' with params [10]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 
1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: 
a foreign key constraint fails (`webdata`.`entry`, CONSTRAINT `FK_2B219D70D823E37A` 
FOREIGN KEY (`section_id`) REFERENCES `section` (`id`))
```

I know what it it means but I just cannot figure out what I should do different here in order to force the `EntityManager` to traverse down my entity graph and delete everything from bottom to top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that in order for `Doctrine` to cascade a `remove` down the entity-relation-graph one would simply annotate the owning side like so:

```
/**
 * Owning side of relation
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Page", mappedBy="website", cascade={"all"}, fetch="EAGER")
 */
private $pages;
```

This, however, really just tells the ORM what you want to happen during an e.g. `remove`. This will not suffice to model what will happen during the actual call to your database. For this, one will have to add an additional `@ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")` to the inverse side, like so:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Website", inversedBy="pages", fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $website;
```

With this everything works as intended. I am also finally able to manually remove entries via `phpMyAdmin` which also gave me errors before.

Answer (score 1):

A cascade is essentially a waterfall, in the sense that it determines where the operations will flow to next.

`Cascade persist` means: when this entry gets persisted, let the operation also flow down to the child entities related to this one. The other operations work in a similar way.

In your case, the cascading seems to be initiated from the child entities. When you call:

```
$entityManager->remove($section);
```

The entity manager only notices cascading operations for `page`, not for `entries`.

When you put the cascade operation on `Section`'s `$entries` instead, you might end up with a cascade delete that removes you page, for similar reasons.

Edit: In terms of annotations, that would make:

In Page:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Website", inversedBy="pages", fetch="EAGER")
 */
private $website;

/**
 * Owning side of relation
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Section", mappedBy="page", fetch="EAGER" , cascade={"all"})
 */
private $sections;
```

In Section:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Page", inversedBy="sections", fetch="EAGER")
 */
private $page;

/**
 * Owning side of relation
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Entry", mappedBy="section", fetch="EAGER", cascade={"all"})
 */
private $entries;
```

In Entry:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Section", inversedBy="entries", fetch="EAGER")
 */
private $section;
```

Are you sure you want to always eagerly fetch everything, btw?

Comment: In fact, yes you are right, you seem to have to initiate the cascading from the parent side. However, I tried that before and I ran into the exact same exception (merely changed the sample before posting because I got confused by the "(INVERSE SIDE)" comment in the `User` class in the docs I linked).

In the end it turned out that `Doctrine` would be fine with the way you explained. However, for when you communicate a `remove` to the database you need to add `@ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")` on your inverse/child side of the relation. I will post my own answer to give an example.

Comment: Also, yes, it seems I need the eager fetching. I know that it's costly. However, my data will change very rarely so that so I should be fine relying on caching here.

Comment: I'm asking because eager loading is not caching - quite the contrary: it performs additional database queries you might not need. If you want caching, best take a look at Doctrine's "second level" cache feature.